# Select2 Library Conflict with custom js code

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, jquery-select2

I have problems with my code, I'm trying to make my select categories to press one of its categories out another select with different options depending on the category selected by the customer, I worked the code but to incorporate the library select2 to give styles to the select or I take the first select categories and does not work and the code to display the other select or leave it for the subcategories but if I design the first select

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>filtro-test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-filtro">
    <div class="filter-template">
        <select id="category-filter">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Elige una Categoria..</option>
          <option value="esferos">Esferos</option>
          <option value="promocionales">Promocionales</option>
          <option value="hogarplus">HogarPlus+</option>
          <option value="juguetes">Juguetes</option>
        </select>
      
        <div class="filter-subcategory esferos">
          <select id="esferos-filter">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Elige una Opcion...</option>
                    <option value="Esferos Publicitarios">Esferos Publicitarios</option>
                    <option value="Esferos Temáticos">Esferos Temáticos</option>
                    <option value="Esferos Ecológicos">Esferos Ecológicos</option>
                    <option value="Esferos de Alta Gama">Esferos de Alta Gama</option>
                    <option value="Resaltadores">Resaltadores</option>
                    <option value="Estuches Kits">Estuches Kits</option>
                    <option value="Lápices">Lápices</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      
        <div class="filter-subcategory promocionales">
          <select id="promocionales-filter">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Elige una Opcion...</option>
            <option value="Bioseguridad">Bioseguridad</option>
                    <option value="Bicicletas y Accesorios">Bicicletas y Accesorios</option>
                    <option value="Agendas">Agendas</option>
                    <option value="Alcancías">Alcancías</option>
                    <option value="Bolsas">Bolsas</option>
                    <option value="Botilitos">Botilitos</option>
                    <option value="Botones">Botones</option>
                    <option value="Cuidado Personal">Cuidado Personal</option>
                    <option value="Hogar">Hogar</option>
                    <option value="Mugs">Mugs</option>
                    <option value="Sombrillas">Sombrillas</option>
                    <option value="Morrales">Morrales</option>
                    <option value="Ecológicos">Ecológicos</option>
                    <option value="Relojes">Relojes</option>
                    <option value="Escolar">Escolar</option>
                    <option value="Oficina">Oficina</option>
                    <option value="Tecnología y Gadgets">Tecnología y Gadgets</option>
                    <option value="Gorras y Camisetas">Gorras y Camisetas</option>
                    <option value="Herramientas">Herramientas</option>
                    <option value="Identificación">Identificación</option>
                    <option value="Linternas y Lamparas">Linternas y Lamparas</option>
                    <option value="Llaveros">Llaveros</option>
                    <option value="Sublimación">Sublimación</option>
                    <option value="Maquinas">Maquinas</option>
                    <option value="Ofertas">Ofertas</option>
                    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                    <option value="USB">USB</option>
                    <option value="Laser">Laser</option>
                    <option value="Insumos">Insumos</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="filter-subcategory hogarplus">
            <select id="hogar-filter">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Elige una Opcion...</option>
                <option value="Cocina">Cocina</option>
                <option value="Hogar+ Hogar">Hogar + Hogar</option>
                <option value="Hogar + Cuidado Personal">Hogar + Cuidado Personal</option>
                <option value="Hogar+ Aseo">Hogar + Aseo</option>
                <option value="Hogar + Mascotas">Hogar + Mascotas</option>
                <option value="Hogar + Morrales">Hogar + Morrales</option>
                <option value="Hogar + Bicicletas">Hogar + Bicicletas</option>
                <option value="Hogar + Herramientas">Hogar + Herramientas</option>
                <option value="Hogar + Automóvil">Hogar + Automóvil</option>
                <option value="Hogar + Tecnología">Hogar + Tecnología</option>
                <option value="Hogar + Botilitos">Hogar + Botilitos</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="filter-subcategory juguetes"> 
            <select id="juguetes-filter">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Elige una Opcion...</option>
                <option value="Nacional">Nacional</option>
                <option value="Carros">Carros</option>
                <option value="Muñecas">Muñecas</option>
                <option value="Didácticos">Didácticos</option>
                <option value="Musicales">Musicales</option>
            </select>
          </div>

      </div>

      <div class="colores">
        <select name="colores" id="colores">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Elige un Color..</option>
            <option value="azul">Azul</option>
            <option value="rojo">Rojo</option>
            <option value="verde">Verde</option>
            <option value="Negro">Negro</option>
            <option value="Gris Oscuro">Gris Oscuro</option>
            <option value="Plata">Plata</option>
            <option value="Gris">Gris</option>
            <option value="Blanco">Blanco</option>
            <option value="Transparente">Transparente</option>
            <option value="Beige">Beige</option>
            <option value="Curuba">Curuba</option>
            <option value="Amarillo">Amarillo</option>
            <option value="Dorado">Dorado</option>
            <option value="naranja">Naranja</option>
            <option value="Bronce">Bronce</option>
            <option value="café">Café</option>
            <option value="Vinotinto">Vinotinto</option>
            <option value="Salmón">Salmón</option>
            <option value="Rosado">Rosado</option>
            <option value="fucsia">Fucsia</option>
            <option value="lila">Lila</option>
            <option value="morado">Morado</option>
            <option value="Azul Oscuro">Azul Oscuro</option>
            <option value="Azul Petroleo">Azul Petroleo</option>
            <option value="Azul Turquesa">Azul Turquesa</option>
            <option value="verde Turquesa">Verde Turquesa</option>
            <option value="Azul Claro">Azul Claro</option>
            <option value="verde claro">Verde Claro</option>
            <option value="verde oscuro">Verde Oscuro</option>
            <option value="madera">Madera</option>
            <option value="bambú">Bambú</option>
            <option value="fucsia claro">Fucsia Claro</option>
            <option value="Rosado fuerte">Rosado Fuerte</option>
            <option value="Terracota">Terracota</option>
            <option value="verde aguacate">Verde Aguacate</option>
            <option value="piel">Piel</option>
            <option value="Verde biche">Verde Biche</option>
            <option value="verde limon">Verde Limon</option>
            <option value="oro rosa">Oro Rosa</option>
            <option value="violeta claro">Violeta Claro</option>
            <option value="verde menta">Verde Menta</option>
            <option value="palo rosa">Palo Rosa</option>
            <option value="pastel">Pastel</option>
            <option value="cobre">Cobre</option>
            <option value="blanco - azul">Blanco - Azul</option>
            <option value="blanco - rojo">Blanco - Rojo</option>
            <option value="blanco - verde">Blanco - Verde</option>
            <option value="blanco - negro">Blanco - Negro</option>
            <option value="craft">Craft</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-filtrar">
      <button>Filtrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/select-test.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/filtro-test.js"></script>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const categoryFilter = document.getElementById('category-filter');
    const subcategories = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-subcategory');

    // Oculta todas las subcategorías al cargar la página
    subcategories.forEach(subcategory => {
      subcategory.style.display = 'none';
    });

    categoryFilter.addEventListener('change', function() {
      const selectedCategory = this.value;

      // Oculta todas las subcategorías
      subcategories.forEach(subcategory => {
        subcategory.style.display = 'none';
      });

      if (selectedCategory) {
        // Muestra la subcategoría correspondiente a la categoría seleccionada
        document.querySelector(`.filter-subcategory.${selectedCategory}`).style.display = 'block';
      }
    });
  });
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#category-filter').select2({
        theme: 'classic',
        width: '300px',
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#colores').select2({
        theme: 'classic',
        width: '200px',
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#esferos-filter').select2({
        theme: 'classic',
        width: '200px',
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#promocionales-filter').select2({  
        theme: 'classic',
        width: '200px',
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hogar-filter').select2({
        theme: 'classic',
        width: '200px',
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#juguetes-filter').select2({
        theme: 'classic',
        width: '200px',
    });
});
```